# Using variours analyzers in Elasticsearch is getting ambigious

Tags: c#, linq

I was trying to add some analyzers in my program in Elasticsearch.
But it shows an error while adding the `.Property` such as

> Error 1   'Nest.CreateIndexDescriptor' does not contain a definition for 'Property' and no extension method 'Property' accepting a first argument of type 'Nest.CreateIndexDescriptor' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Can u plz help me to solve this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Nest;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder;
using System.IO;

namespace MenuAnalyzer2
{
     public class Program
    {
        public static Uri node;
        public static ConnectionSettings settings;
        public static ElasticClient client;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
            settings = new ConnectionSettings(node, defaultIndex: "asd");
            client = new ElasticClient(settings);

            var indexsettings = new IndexSettings();
            indexsettings.NumberOfReplicas =1;
            indexsettings.NumberOfShards = 6;

            client.CreateIndex("asd", c => c
                .Index("asd")
                .InitializeUsing(indexsettings)
                .Property(prop => prop
                    .MultiField(mf => mf
                        .Name(p => p.Name)
                        .Fields(f => f
                            .String(
                                s =>
                                    s.Name(n => n.Name)
                                        .IndexAnalyzer("autocomplete_analyzer")
                                        .IncludeInAll(false)
                                        .Index(FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed))
                            .String(
                                s =>
                                    s.Name(n => n.Name)
                                        .IndexAnalyzer("fulltext")
                                        .IncludeInAll(false)
                                        .Index(FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed))
                        )
                    )
                )
                .AddMapping<Items>(m => m.MapFromAttributes()));


            PerformMatchPhrase();
            Items obj;
            string filepath = "D:\\food.csv";
            DataTable res = ConvertCSVtoDataTable(filepath);
            List<DataRow> list = res.AsEnumerable().ToList();

            foreach (var row in list)
            {  
                    //client = new ElasticClient(settings);
                    obj = new Items();
                    obj.itemID = row.Field<string>("ID");
                    obj.item = row.Field<string>("Foodies");
                    obj.price = row.Field<string>("Amount");
                    obj.ac = row.Field<string>("Ac");
                    client.Index(obj);

            }

        }

        public static DataTable ConvertCSVtoDataTable(string strFilePath)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(strFilePath);
            string[] headers = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            foreach (string header in headers)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(header);
            }
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                string[] rows = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
                {
                    dr[i] = rows[i];
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            return dt;
        }

          public static void PerformMatchPhrase()
        {
            List<Items> mat = new List<Items>();
            var result =
                client.Search<Items>(s => s
               .Query(q => q.MatchPhrase(m => m.OnField("item").Query("masala"))));
                //.Query(q => q.MatchAll("postText"))));
            if(result!=null)
            {
                if (result.Documents.Count <Items>()> 0)
                    mat = result.Documents.ToList <Items>();
            }
            foreach(Items m in mat)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(m.itemID);
                Console.WriteLine(m.item);
                Console.WriteLine(m.price);
                Console.WriteLine(m.ac);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

    }
}`
```